# How to deploy a nuxt application on a hosting?

Tags: deployment, nuxt3

It is the first time I use nuxt and node technologies.
I have a project that uses an API for the backend that just deal with a mysql database and is placed under the server directory.
At the moment things runs well in the developement  environment.

I want to have this running in my hosting. This hosting can run a node application for the backend.
Nevertheless I am a bit confused on how to proceed to upload all this stuff.

I understood (but maybe I am wrong) that, as I want my site prerendered, I should use the nuxt generate command to generate the prerendered pages of the frontend upload all the files in the output/public folder in my domain pointed folder.
But what I am wondering is what to do for the backend? Is there a specific command to run before any upload. And then what to upload and how to install the dependencies ?

I feel a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use cloud solution like Cloudflare Pages to deploy Nuxt application and run API on hosting?

Comment: No. I will have a look at it.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt's official documentation, [Deploy a Nuxt App](https://nuxt.com/deploy), provides very detailed configuration and deployment steps for different hosting providers.